# ReactJS error getting object assigned from axios call to api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

**I have the following code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Dashboard extends Component {
     state = {
         name : 'randomname',
         apiData: {}
};

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('https://api_url/getdata)
    .then(res => {
        const apiData = res.data
        this.setState({apiData});
    });
}

render() {
  const { name, apiData} = this.state;

  //THIS WORKS
  var objTest = [{game_id: 2}]; //This is returned from apical
  console.log(objTest[0].game_id);

  console.log(apiData); //logs the following: [{game_id: 2}]
  console.log(apiData[0]); //logs the following: {game_id: 2}
  console.log(apiData[0].game_id); //Error occurs See error below

  return (  
    <div className="wrap">
         TESTING
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default Dashboard;
```

While testing and trying to get game_id using: `console.log(apiData[0].game_id);` I get the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'apiData[0].game_id')

I would like to know why this works when I declare a variable and assign it the same values as the api call returns. But it does not work then I'm assigning the api call to apiData. It can only access `apiData[0]` which returns `{game_id:2}` , but cannot access apiData[0].game_id.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: does `console.log(objTest[0].game_id);` works?

Comment: This seems like the issue of the lifecycle method. Check for the data availability and then do the console.log. render() runs before the componentDidMount.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is the order of life cycle methods. During mounting phase the constructor and then the render method is called. ComponentDidMount is not called yet and hence your state is empty. The reason you are not getting error when you log apiData or apiData[0] is it simply loggs empty array or object during initial render call (mounting phase) and then the actual object during the second render after componentDidMount(updateing phase). But when you try to call the property(game_id), you get an error(undefined) during the mounting phase since you are calling it on an empty array/object.

The solution is check for the existance of the parent object before calling the property on it , for example , usine optional chaining (JS2020 new future) which checks apiData[0], the error should be fixed just py appending "?" after the object. you can also use other methods for older JS.

```
console.log(apiData[0]?.game_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

ComponentDidMount is triggered after the render method has loaded. Which means that console.log(apiData[0]) is calling the default state first before componentDidMount method is called.

Default state is an empty object here and not an array. So the index 0 of apiData is nothing. Changing the default state to `apiData: [{game_id: null}]` will give you the result and state will change once the componentDidMount is triggered and the api is successfully called.

This however is not the best approach. It's just to make things clear and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Simply defined one flag in the state and check whether your data is available or not once you get data change that flag and and load your component element accordingly.

see below solution for your problem statement.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Dashboard extends Component {
     state = {
         loading:true,
         name : 'randomname',
         apiData: {}
};

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('https://api_url/getdata').then(res => {
        this.setState({apiData:res.data, loading:false});
    });
}

render() {
  const { name, apiData, loading} = this.state;

  //THIS WORKS
  var objTest = [{game_id: 2}]; //This is returned from apical
  console.log(objTest[0].game_id);

  console.log(apiData); //logs the following: [{game_id: 2}]
  console.log(apiData[0]); //logs the following: {game_id: 2}
  console.log(apiData[0].game_id); //Error occurs See error below

  return (  
    <div className="wrap">
         {loading ? <div>Loading ...</div> : <div className="wrap">TESTING</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default Dashboard;
```